# How to delete and resize matplotlib annotations?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the basic `axis.annotate(str(i))` function to show values along the points of my graph. The problem is quite quickly they get to bunched together. So I have two questions: How can I remove an annotation? And how can I make one smaller (font size)?

Here is the reference to the annotation method: 
http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate

I have done my research and surprisingly found nothing. Cheers.

Comment: The problem of bunching annotations has been tackled [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735808/annotation-auto-placement-matploylib-pyplot-or-list-annotations) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938541/how-to-improve-the-label-placement-for-matplotlib-scatter-chart-code-algorithm) may be equally of interest.

Comment: Looks interesting. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`axis.annotate(str(i))` returns an axes Annotation object. You need to assign a variable to it and then you manipulate it however you want.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(range(5))
text = ax.annotate(xy = (2,2), s='asdf')
# use any set_ function to change all the properties
text.set_fontsize(20)
```

Comment: You can delete any artist from the figure using `del`. So in this case `del text` would work.